# How to execute a script that is in a directory to cd into a subdirectory which will cd into its subdirectory and then the command will execute?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have a folder with subdirectories and those subdirectories have more subdirectories where I want the command to be executed. The code below is the script I have made so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `ls -d ./*/`;
do
cd "$i"
 for x in `ls -d ./*/`
 cd "$x"
 gzip -d *.mol2.gz
 mv *.mol2 /path/to/directory
 cd ..
 done
cd ..
done
echo "Finished"
```

Comment: What is your end goal?  What are you trying to achieve here?   It seems like you are running `gzip -d ` at some point then moving thos to `/path/to/directory`.  Look at the `find` manpage and specifically for the `-execdir`  flag

Comment: Your construct ``for i in `ls -d ./*/` `` should more accurately be written as `for i in ./*/`. There's no need for `ls` at all

Comment: Btw.: add a `do` to your second `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're simply asking for this:

```
gunzip */*/*.mol2.gz
mv */*/*.mol2 /path/to/directory
```

No need for any loops, and let the shell do the heavy lifting

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` instead.

```
find . -name "*.mol12.gz" -exec gzip -d {} +
```

Then you can move the files after with find again